# How to select records in DB2 if it exists in current month as weel as previous month?

Tags: c, db2

This is my table.
Assume the current month is June. Previous month is May.If balance amount exists for both current and previous months then populate the balance amount for current month. If balance amount does not exist for current month then populate the value for previous month.

**Input table.**

```
Transaction_Number  Status_Indicator    Balance Amount  Month
20                Y              200             June
20                Y              500              May
21                Y              600             June
21                Y              700              May
22                Y              800             June
23                Y              900              May
```

**Output:**

```
Transaction_Number   Balance_Amount
20             200
21             600
22             800
23             900
```

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: I believe you need to install some [DB2 library](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0602hutchison/) for interfacing the database with C.

Comment: you need `db2 query` or code in `c` to accomplish the task?

Comment: @Siva I need db2 query

Comment: Um, what is the actual data in month?  How do we know that `'June'` comes after `'May'`?  Are these all the same year?  Do we need to worry about wrapping around years?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse This is for the same year.So June should come after May.

Comment: The db doesn't really understand textual months - it doesn't know that `'June'` has any other meaning.  For all it knows, it's somebod's name... so you need some way to tell the db to interpret it as a month, which usually also requires year and day.  This becomes important if you need the month previous to January... the db needs a way to determine the correct year, too.  Which is why people tend to store first-of-month dates.

Comment: What platform is DB2 on? What is the DB2 version/release?

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is not a tested code... right now I don't have the control center.

```
select currentmonth.Transaction_Number,(currentmonth.data1+previousmonth.data2)
from
(select Transaction_Number, sum(Balance Amount) data2
from <<table name>>
where month=MONTH(current date)-1
group by Transaction_Number) previousmonth
Left join
(select Transaction_Number, sum(Balance Amount) data1
from <<table name>>
where month=MONTH(current date)
group by Transaction_Number) currentmonth
on previousmonth.Transaction_Number = currentmonth.Transaction_Number
group by Transaction_Number
```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: Well, this'll fail when the current date is January.  However, I'd be more concerned about whether he actually has a usable date.

Comment: If all rows are for the current year, then MONTHNAME(CURRENT DATE) can be used as a basis for testing the "Month" column. Obviously the table is seriously in need of being redefined if this will be any kind of permanent process. But it could be okay as a temporary table for some ad hoc query that will only run once. Or maybe all that's needed is hard-coding the month names, if this is a one-time query.